# error: LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt in QtCreator 5.0.2

Tags: qt

I get the following error " LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt" when i build my solution in QtCreator 5.0.2.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Re-run qmake and rebuild your project. Ideally, simply delete the entire build directory.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but again a new project open and build the same error is occured.Am new in Qt....

Comment: Can you build any of examples supplied with Qt? If you can't, then you have a corrupt installation. Does your pre-built variant of Qt match your compiler? You can't mix C++ compilers. What is your compiler?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution in another thread. Just include the following line in your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /INCREMENTAL:NO
```